# removing ical download links in DPCalendar Lite calendar listing

Tags: joomla-extensions

I would like to remove the ical download links from the list of calendars in DPCalendar Lite ([illustrative bit of screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjyN8.jpg)) but have not been able to find a configuration option for this.  Is there a way to do it without editing source?  Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

Well I would still really prefer if there was a configuration option, but for anyone else who wants to do this, the code to modify is in

```
/com_dpcalendar/site/layouts/calendar/calendarlist.php
```

starting at line 49, remove or comment out:

```
    <?php
    if (!$calendar->external)
    { ?>
        [ <a href="<?php echo DPCalendarHelperRoute::getCalendarIcalRoute($calendar->id)?>">
            <?php echo JText::_('COM_DPCALENDAR_VIEW_CALENDAR_TOOLBAR_ICAL')?>
        </a> ]

        <?php if (!DPCalendarHelper::isFree() && !JFactory::getUser()->guest)
        {
        ?>
            [ <a href="<?php echo trim(JUri::base(), '/') . '/components/com_dpcalendar/caldav.php/calendars/' . JFactory::getUser()->username . '/dp-' . $calendar->id?>">
                <?php echo JText::_('COM_DPCALENDAR_VIEW_PROFILE_TABLE_CALDAV_URL_LABEL')?>
            </a> ]
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```